# How do i write Simple inline asm instruction from C on Linux 64 bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

i am writing a simple c program and my requirement is to print RIP(Instruction Pointer) from some function of the program. i dont want to use ptrace.

the one thing i tried with inline asm is:
**asm("movl %%rip, %0;" : "=r"(val) )**
this should copy my rip register value to variable val, but i am getting compilation error.

if i use ebp/esp which are base pointer and stack pointers for 32 bit machine, i dont get any compilation error and my val has some hexadecimal number assigned.

i have few questions here:

1) as my machine is 63 bit, how was above instruction able to read 32 bit registers?

2) why i am not able to read any register for 64 bit, is there any issue b'caz of **'r'**?

3) when i use eip which is for 32 bit i get compilation error, does it mean IP registers are restricted for reading?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Your machine is *64* bit, not 63 bit =).  You were able to read the the 32-bit registers because you are compiling and running your program as a 32-bit executable[1].
2. You are unable to read the 64-bit registers because you are compiling and running your program as a 32-bit executable.  Yes, you have a 64-bit processor, but it can still run 32-bit executables (if your OS supports it, which yours clearly does), and evidently your compiler tool chain builds 32-bit by default.  If you are using `gcc`, try using the `-m64` flag, or read the compiler documentation for more information.
3. Unlike `rip`, the `eip` register cannot be directly accessed.  You can get the value of `eip` in the manner described by **Jim** in his answer.

[1] you would be able to read the 32-bit registers from a 64-bit executable anyway; the 32-bit registers are still available in 64-bit mode, just like you can access the 16-bit registers in 32-bit mode.

---

There are a few problems still in your example:

First, although `rip` is accessible in 64-bit mode, it's accessible as an addressing mode; it's not a normal register.  If you want to load its value, you need to use `LEA`, not `MOV`.

Second, because `rip` is a 64-bit register, you need to use the `q` suffix on your instructions instead of `l`.  Here's a sample program with these two issues addressed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint64_t ip;
    asm("leaq (%%rip), %0;": "=r"(ip));
    printf("rip is 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", ip);
    return 0;
}
```

which seems to work just fine on my machine.

Comment: asm("movl (%%rip), %0;" : "=r"(val) ) this statement assigns some value to my variable, but asm("movl %%rip, %0;" : "=r"(val) ) don't and gives compilation Error: suffix or operands invalid for `mov'. 

again the value which i get from 1st statement does not match with the nm result of my library. i assume that the library has information about the IP address and respective symbol for the functions. 

is it the correct behavior? the results are same even when i use "-m64" flag. my machine by default has 64 bit settings.

Comment: i think one more syntax is correct for only reading registers. that is **register int iRIP asm("rip");**; but this too gives compilation error like "error: invalid register name for ΓÇÿiRIPΓÇÖ". it does not give compilation errors for other 64 bit registers. i made it sure that i compiled with -m64 flag of gcc.
it looks that rip register cannot be accessed.

Comment: which of the above syntax is more reliable, b'caz both gives output as different hex numbers for RSP.

Comment: @Sandeep P: My answer is updated with a working example for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value of the EIP register by doing:

```
    call a  ; this pushes the value of EIP onto the stack
a:          
    pop ebx ; pops the value of EIP into register ebx
```

and then you can just read ebx.

Comment: Note that this time-honored trick isn't necessary on 64-bit; you can just read from `rip`.