# Substitutes for x86 assembly 'call' instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, call

What are some alternatives to the x86 call instruction?
Maybe something like a push of the return address then a jump?

Also is their a command for obtaining the current position in memory?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341248/how-do-i-write-simple-inline-asm-instruction-from-c-on-linux-64-bit/3344243#3344243) along with the ambient question.

Answer (score 27):

The `call` instruction actually does this for you. For example `call my_func` would do something like:

```
push ret_address
jmp my_func
```

A subsequent `ret` call would just use the address you just pushed to `jmp` back in a sense. Is there a specific reason that you don't want to use `call` or is it not available for you?
For current position in memory you can try to read the `eip` register (can't write to it).

Comment: I'm injecting a asm code stub that calls internal functions withing another process (using C#). Basically was wondering if their would be a more elegant way of calling that said function without disrupting any registers or the stack (so as to preserve them before the call.) Another solution i used is just to write a jump instruction follow by the function address statically (sorta how windows handles dll functions.) However this meant keeping track of the buffer size of the injected code, which in my opinion is inelegant but looks like that is the only option at the moment.

Comment: Also i think i can use an indirect call.

Comment: Yeah you can use an indirect call, something else you can use a jump detour if you want to replace the function call altogether and have it execute your code instead.

Comment: In addition to a jump detour, if it is needed to replace the function call altogether, you can patch relevant call/jump offsets directly in the code. The custom replacement function should have the same signature as the original one. Of course this does not work for indirect calls and jumps but it can still be helpful.

Comment: You **can** write to the EIP register, the instruction is just not called MOV but JMP.

Comment: I was just thinking about it a little bit. Couldn't one just do a relative call of zero offset then just pop the return address? Problem is it sacrifices a register.

Comment: @Bo can you? I thought there were mechanisms to prevent this in some OS I might be wrong though as I've never really tried to write anything to EIP since the processor itself handles it.

Comment: @rick, yes, you can. The trick Kerrek SB referred to in the comment to your question does just that: `call $0x5; pop %ebx`. And yes, clobbering of `%ebx` can be a problem but it's usually manageable. What to do depends on how you plan to use that saved value of the instruction pointer.

Comment: You can prevent the clobbering of a register by just using `[esp]`. For example, `jmp +0x5; pop eax; xor ecx, ebx` can be replaced with `jmp +0x5; xor ecx, [esp]`. When you're done with the address, just do `add esp, 4` (or `sub esp, 4` on an upward growing stack).

Comment: @JesusRamos: A jump / call or ret instruction is literally setting EIP, making the CPU execute something other than the next instruction.  If it were true you'd never written EIP, that would mean all code you'd ever written was straight-line with no branching, including not returning anywhere.  (Could be possible if you'd only ever written inline asm and let the compiler make loops / conditionals).  See also [Why can't you set the instruction pointer directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150027) / [Reading program counter directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/599968)

Comment: e.g. `ret` is just how x86 spells "pop eip".

Answer (score 7):

You can just push a dword value and jmp to the procedure. The push would be the return address :

```
push return_address (push eax if address in eax)
jmp call_address
```

Remember to also push arguments if they exist for that particular call.

What do you mean by current position in memory ? I suppose that you mean the current instruction pointer. You cannot get that directly, but you can use a seh handler(structured exception handler) to get that value upon causing a handled exception.

Answer (score 3):

If I don't get something mixed up I would say it depends. As you can see [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) there are near and far calls, but let's just consider the near call. There are again two possibilities

```
E8 <offset> # relative
FF <address> # absolute
```

whereas `FF` means an absolute "jump" and `E8` indeed means relative to current `eip`.

So if you have e.g.

```
E8 32 45 ab 6f
```

which means

```
call 0x3245ab6f
```

This would translate to

```
push %eip
add $0x3245ab6f, %eip
```

and not

```
push %eip
jmp $0x3245ab6f
```

Comment: Note that `call` pushes the address of one-past-the-end of itself, i.e. the address of the next instruction.  x86 doesn't have an architecturally-visible `%eip`, so you should at least comment your pseudo-code to explain that your `%eip` is the already-incremented EIP, after adding the length of the call instruction.  (But yes, the relative displacement is relative to the end of the instruction, i.e. the return address, just like for 64-bit RIP-relative addressing.)

Comment: Don't x86 store data in little-endian? Therefore, why is ```call 0x3245ab6f``` and ```E8 32 45 ab 6f``` not in little endian?