# Operand type mismatch for `push'

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I need help with C code that uses ASSEMBLY parts. GCC has a problem compiling the assembly, error:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o sthread.o sthread.c
sthread.c: In function ‘sthread_create’:
sthread.c:159:57: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
     t->context = __sthread_initialize_context(t->memory + DEFAULT_STACKSIZE, f, arg);
                                                         ^
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 -pedantic   -c -o queue.o queue.c
as -g  -o glue.o glue.s
glue.s: Assembler messages:
glue.s:32: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
<wbudowane>: polecenia dla obiektu 'glue.o' nie powiodły się
make: *** [glue.o] Błąd 1
```

Code in question:

```
__sthread_switch:
    # preserve CPU state on the stack, with exception of stack pointer, instruction pointer first, reverse order
    pushq %rip  #line 32
    pushf
    pushq %rdi
    pushq %rsi
    pushq %rbp
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rdx
    pushq %rcx
    pushq %rax

    # Call the high-level scheduler with the current context as an argument
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    movq    scheduler_context, %rsp
    call    __sthread_scheduler
```

Comment: Related: [You cannot access the instruction pointer directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333413/why-cant-you-set-the-instruction-pointer-directly). What is it that you want to achieve? Why do you need access to RIP? See the linked questions for alternative ways of accessing RIP.

Comment: `rip` is not a general purpose register and there is no dedicated `push rip` instruction either.

Comment: You generally get the equivalent of `push rip` as part of a `call` instruction. When you enter a function, the `rip` of the caller is already saved on the stack,

Answer (score 6):

With `X86_64` you cannot push the `%rip`, in fact you cannot access it directly at all.

If you still need to do it, you can do

```
leaq 0(%rip), %rax # Or any other GPR that is free
pushq %rax
```

OR

```
callq . + 5          # no label, hard-code instruction length
# or
callq 1f ;  1:       # with a local numbered label
```

Although I am not sure **why** you would want to stash the `%rip`, if you restore it from here, the execution will continue from the push instruction. Is there any value to that? You need to rethink your thread switching logic.

Comment: `call rel32` with a rel32=0 is the same thing as `push rip`.  It turns out that CPUs more recent than PPro special-case it, so it might be more efficient than lea/push.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had written that before. Edited it out because wasn't sure and according to my understand will also mess with return prediction. But anyway some kind of context switch is happening here. Should be okay I guess

Comment: @PeterCordes can you check if the instruction I have added now is correct? I am a bit unsure.

Comment: @PeterCordes does `callq *(%rip)` do an indirect call?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `*` means.  It assembles to `ff 15 00 00 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]`.  Without the `*`, `call (%rip)` just warns `indirect call without '*'`.  I'm not sure of any "clean" way to encode `call +0` without a label or hard-coding the instruction length.  Of course you can encode it manually with `.byte 0xe8, 0,0,0,0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes and `call *%rip` also does not assemble. I think local labels are the "nicest" option.

Answer (score 1):

To push RIP, simply execute [`call`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) with a zero displacement.

```
call next_insn
next_insn:
```

So the jump part of `call` is a no-op, so you just get the effect of pushing a return address (i.e. the current RIP).

Fun fact: [`call rel32=0` is a special case and doesn't unbalance the return address predictor stack](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0) on CPUs more recent than PPro.  So `call next_insn / pop eax` is useful in 32-bit mode as an equivalent to `lea (%rip), %rax`.

It's still a branch instruction, and still decodes to multiple uops (unlike a `push` of a GPR which is 1 micro-fused uop), so `lea (%rip), %rax` ; `push %rax` may be more efficient.